# How can a @JsonView working with jersey

Tags: jersey, jackson, json-view

I want to return different fields with different views for one object. But it always return all the fields. 
I created 3 different views:

```
public class Views {
    public static class PublicView { }
    public static class ExtendedPublicView extends PublicView { }
    public static class InternalView extends ExtendedPublicView { }
}
```

Then in the User.java

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class User {

    @JsonView(Views.PublicView.class)
    private String username;

    @JsonView(Views.PublicView.class)
    private String employeeName;

    @JsonView(Views.ExtendedPublicView.class)
    private Date birthday;  

    @JsonView(Views.ExtendedPublicView.class)
    private String mobile;
}
```

Then add @JsonView to

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@JsonView(Views.PublicView.class)
public GenericResponse auth(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("password") String password ){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok , i fix this several days ago.
I check the source code of jackson I used that time , there were nothing doing about the @json view. That version I remember is 1.8.*
Now I change to a newer one . it works